# Making batch tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-processing

So I have this problem of making batch in my code, the thing is, I tried to search how we do batching but all I found was using some method like next_batch in MNIST sample program. I would really appreciate if someone could actually give me some tips on how I should make batch in my program below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_validation
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(20160612)
tf.set_random_seed(20160612)

#this is input data, data is a 7x86594 and label is a 5x86594
data2 = pd.read_csv('rawdata.csv', sep=',', header=None) 
data = np.array(data2)
label2=pd.read_csv('class.csv', sep='\t', header=None)
label=np.array(label2)

train_x,test_x,train_t,test_t=cross_validation.train_test_split(data,label,test_size=0.1,random_state=None)

#this is supposed to be neural size in hidden layer
num_units = 15

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 7])
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 5])

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([7, num_units], mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_units]))
hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, w1) + b1)

w0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_units, 5]))
b0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5]))

p = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(hidden1, w0) + b0)


loss =  -tf.reduce_sum(t * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(p,1e-10,1.0)))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(p, 1), tf.argmax(t, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

#this is how i think batching is

batch_size = 100
for j in range(0, 86594, batch_size):
    xs,ys= train_x[j:j+batch_size],  train_t[j:j+batch_size]


i = 0

for _ in range(4000):
    i += 1

    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: xs, t: ys})
    if i % 100 == 0:
        loss_val, acc_val = sess.run([loss, accuracy],feed_dict={x:test_x, t: test_t})
        print ('Step: %d, Loss: %f, Accuracy: %f'% (i, loss_val, acc_val))
```

The result of this program, of course, isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

Keep extracting the batches of your data and keep feeding them to the network for training. In each epoch, all the samples of your training dataset should be run once. So you can rewrite your code like this:

Required part of code only:

```
epochs = 4000
batch_size = 100
for epoch_no in range(epochs):
    for index, offset in enumerate(range(0, 86594, batch_size)):
        xs, ys = train_x[offset: offset + batch_size], train_t[offset: offset + batch_size]
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: xs, t: ys})

        if index % 100 == 0:
            loss_val, acc_val = sess.run([loss, accuracy], feed_dict = {x: test_x, t: test_t})
            print ('Epoch %d, Step: %d, Loss: %f, Accuracy: %f'% (epoch_no, index, loss_val, acc_val))
```

Comment: i am sorry but if i replace my code with your code, it makes the program run step 0 for like 500 times, i tried this "nested for" like this too but the result was just like the program run step 0 for many times. did i misplace the code for batch section?

Comment: @mstfa23 I was printing in a wrong manner. Now, it will print for all epochs at every 100th step of training. Run it and check again. Also replace the above code with all your code from your line of code `batch_size = 100`.

Comment: I tried to run the edited code but instead of getting epochs at every 100th, I got epochs at every number for 9 times and steps for 0, 100.. till 800 and it goes to epoch 1 for 9 times and each one has step 0 till 800 (9 times as well). I placed the edited code to my code at the line from batch_size as what you said too.

Comment: @mstfa23 Ya, exactly, it will print at every 100th step of each epoch just the way you mentioned. If you want to print only at specific epoch, say every 50th epoch and that too you want every 100th step only, then you need to modify that condition to: `if index % 100 == 0 and epoch_no % 50 == 0:`. Let me know when exactly you want it to print? i.e at which epoch and which step no of that epoch.